# Querying Through Active Directory, stuck with cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'

Tags: c#, string, active-directory, int, type-conversion

i am currently working on a project that i called user extract, which contains a list box of users from my active directory based on my domain, when a certain user is selected i get all the information of that user, such as name, email, phone, etc but some values in the active directory are stored as integer 8 value, i am able to use the GetDirectoryEntry().Properties and display all the information on a textbox only if the value is a string in the active directory. from the below code the home directory, home drive, when created, when changed are all working because either they are of the format generalized time or string, but account expires, last logoff, bad password time dont work because they are of type integer 8 and i tried:

```
       if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["lastLogonTimestamp"].Value != null)
            lastlogon.Text = rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["lastLogonTimestamp"].Value.ToString();
            int x = Int32.Parse(lastlogon.Text);
            lastlogon.Text = x;
```

The ERROR I GET:

```
Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'
```

ANY HELP IS REALLY APPRECIATED, THANKS GUYS!!!!

here is the code i am using:

```
 private void ShowUserInformation(SearchResult rs)
        if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["accountExpires"].Value != null)
            accountexpires.Text = rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["accountExpires"].Value.ToString();

        if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["homeDrive"].Value != null)
            homedrive.Text = rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["homeDrive"].Value.ToString();

       if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["homeDirectory"].Value != null)
            homedirectory.Text = rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["homeDirectory"].Value.ToString();

       if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["whenCreated"].Value != null)
            WhenCreate.Text = rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["whenCreated"].Value.ToString();       

       if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["lastLogoff"].Value != null)
            lastloggedoff.Text = rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["lastLogoff"].Value.ToString();

        if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["badPasswordTime"].Value != null)
            badpassword.Text = rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["badPasswordTime"].Value.ToString();
```

> the following works thanks to DJ Kraze

```
private void showuserinfo() 
{ 
    PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain); 
    UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx); 
    PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser); 
    foreach (var found in srch.FindAll()) 
    { 
        try 
        { 
            UserPrincipal foundUser = found as UserPrincipal; 
            if (foundUser != null) 
            { 
                foundUser.IsAccountLockedOut(); 
                lastlogon.Text = (foundUser.LastLogon).ToString(); 
            } 
        } 
        catch (Exception ex) 
        { 
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Call `ToString` like `lastlogon.Text = x.ToString();`

Comment: `lastlogon.Text = x` your error message is telling you exactly what's going on .. a simple suggestion would be to use the debugger and step thru the code and you will see that when it errors on that line.. it basically saying that a text field for example textbox can not hold an integer value.. Convert it to String or use `lastlogon.Text = x.ToString();`

Comment: @Habib i tried you solution now i am getting this error: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: @DJKRAZE i went through the debugger, now the new error say input string was not in a correct format, the rs.GetDirectoryEntry().properties only has an option to take the value.tostring() but the error is caused because the incoming value itself is of type intger 8 so to make it brief i think a solution such as get the direct int value and set it to the text box but i dont know if textbox would allow to display integer values. so how else can i get the int value directly from active directory and display it in a textbox?

Comment: you have to be familiar with `Casting` of `Objects` especially in active directory.. for example `Properties["lastLogonTimestamp"].Value` I would expect to see an assignment of something like this `var someValue = (string)Properties["lastLogonTimestamp"].Value` and or appending the `.ToString()` at the end.. have you looked up how to do this on the internet there are lots of examples of how to do this in regards to getting Properties within ActiveDirectory. I will post a better example in a second, I use AD on a daily basis

Comment: [DirectoryEntries.FindMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39zxbb5w(v=vs.110).aspx) || [SearchResult.GetDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.searchresult.getdirectoryentry(v=vs.110).aspx) also have you considered using `PrincipalContext` I feel that it would serve your purpose better in my own opinion..

Comment: @DJKRAZE Thanks for the valuable comment, actually new to casting after reading other posts and googling i tried: 
            if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["lastLogon"].Value != null)
              lastlogon.Text = (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["lastLogon"].Value.ToString());
                 int  x; 
                    x =  Int32.Parse(lastlogon.Text);
                    lastlogon.Text = x.ToString(); first off i went through the debugger and noticed that lastlogon.Text = "System.__ComObject" is the value i am retrieving from the active directory, input not correct format err.

Comment: I would highly suggest refactoring your code and using `PrincipalContext` it and you may have to write some small AD code or google how to use C# DirectoryEntry GetDirectory method..tons of examples online

Comment: @DJKRAZE i used Principal context earlier to fill the users and groups list box: private void filluser()
        {
            // create your domain context
            PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain); UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx);PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser);foreach (var found in srch.FindAll())
{ try
{UserPrincipal foundUser = found as UserPrincipal;
if (foundUser != null){
foundUser.IsAccountLockedOut();
user.Items.Add(foundUser.GivenName + " " + foundUser.Surname + " " + "[" + foundUser.SamAccountName + "]");}

Comment: @DJKRAZE your idea works, so something like foundUser.LastLogon from the previous messages gives me the value, so you suggest i create a private void lastlogon() { and call this where users_selected_indexchanged??? do this only for those crazy integer 8 values, the string are okay, gotta love string values :)

Comment: you want to create a method that returns lastlogon I would think something like `private bool LastLogon(string user){ return your boolean assignment}` does this make sense..? do you understand what `void` means..? it does not return a value.. if you want to return a value from a `void` inside your method signature use the `out param key word` and assign or initialize it within the local method

Comment: @DJKRAZE Thanks a lot buddy: The following works -  private void showuserinfo()
{            
 PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
 UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx);    
 PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser);
 foreach (var found in srch.FindAll())
 {
 try
 {
 UserPrincipal foundUser = found as UserPrincipal;
if (foundUser != null)
{
foundUser.IsAccountLockedOut();
lastlogon.Text = (foundUser.LastLogon).ToString();
}
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
 MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
 }
}
 }

Comment: Glad that I could help out have a great evening .. happy coding :)

Answer (score 2):

```
if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["lastLogonTimestamp"].Value != null)
            lastlogon.Text = rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["lastLogonTimestamp"].Value.ToString();
            int x = Int32.Parse(lastlogon.Text);
            lastlogon.Text = x.ToString();
```

Watchout that `x` is an `int` and not a `string`, so you need to cast that before assigning it to `lastlogon.Text` 's property.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response, however even with casting i had issues with the data that was actually coming in from the active directory such as "System.__ComObject" so from what DJ Kraze suggested i used the PrincipalContext, UserPrincipal, Principal searcher and was able to successfully retrieve all the interger 8 values and set it = to my text box.